# How to make Angular CLI stop including a given typings file on my project?

Tags: typescript, angular-cli, typescript-typings, jointjs, angular-cli-v6

I have added JointJs to my Angular CLI project, but I keep getting typing errors when trying to build:

[image: Typings errors]

Note that the errors refer to the file `node_modules/jointjs/types/joinjs.d.ts` file, but that is not the correct file I need. The correct one that should work is actually under the `dist` folder, at `node_modules/jointjs/dist/jointjs.d.ts`, and I see that there are other messages about that file, so it is being included as well.

All I need is for `node_modules/jointjs/types/joinjs.d.ts` to get excluded so I can stop getting errors about it.

**How can a specific typings file be excluded from the project?**

I'm trying to make JointJs 2.1.0 work with Angular 6 and Angular CLI 6.

Any help here is greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE:**

I tried adding this types folder to the `exclude` section of my tsconfig.json, as well the tsconfig.app.ts file:

```
"exclude": [
  "node_modules/jointjs/types/*"
]
```

as well listing the individual files that should be excluded:

```
"exclude": [
  "node_modules/jointjs/types/geometry.d.ts",
  "node_modules/jointjs/types/vectorizer.d.ts",
  "node_modules/jointjs/types/joint.d.ts",
  "node_modules/jointjs/types/joint.head.d.ts"
]
```

...hoping it these files would become invisible to the compiler, but same errors persist.

Answer (score 1):

You could try changing the path to the type.d.ts in `tsconfig.json`
Here you just change the path lead to your `type.d.ts`, the rest should keep the same in your app

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "baseUrl": "...",
  "paths": {
    "node_modules/jointjs/types/*": ["node_modules/jointjs/dist/*"],//Here
  },
  ...
}
```

Hope this could help.